# How can I fit the app to full screen size when app is opening with .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, maui, maui-blazor

When the app is opened, the app is not opened in full-screen size. I want to open the app in full-screen size when it is opening. How can I set it to full screen when the app is opening in Blazor hybrid app using .net 7?

This is the code of the function that I implemented in App.xaml.cs file to solve this issue but it didn't work. How to fix it?

```
protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
{
    Window window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);
    window.Activated += Window_Activated;
    return window;
}

private async void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const int DefaultWidth = 1024;
    const int DefaultHeight = 800;

    var window = sender as Window;

    //change window size
    window.Width = DefaultWidth;
    window.Height = DefaultHeight;

    await window.Dispatcher.DispatchAsync(() => { });

    var disp = DeviceDisplay.Current.MainDisplayInfo;

    //move to screen center
    window.X = (disp.Width / disp.Density - window.Width) / 2;
    window.Y = (disp.Height / disp.Density + window.Height) / 2;
}
```

Comment: Can the code in my answer help you?

Comment: I am pleased to inform you that both methods you suggested have been successful. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the following code in the MauiProgram.cs:

```
var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
           
                  .UseMauiApp<App>()
                  .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                  {
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                  });
#if WINDOWS
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>  
        {  
            events.AddWindows(wndLifeCycleBuilder =>  
            {  
                wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>  
                {  
                //    window.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = false;  
                    IntPtr hWnd = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
                    Microsoft.UI.WindowId myWndId = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(hWnd);  
                    var _appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(myWndId);  
                    _appWindow.SetPresenter(Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindowPresenterKind.FullScreen);   
                 //if you want to full screen, you can use this line
               // (_appWindow.Presenter as Microsoft.UI.Windowing.OverlappedPresenter).Maximize();   
                //if you want to Maximize the window, you can use this line                    
                });  
            });  
        });
#endif
```

Or you can try to put the following code in the MainPage.cs:

```
protected override void OnHandlerChanged()
      {
            base.OnHandlerChanged();
#if WINDOWS
                  var window = App.Current.Windows.FirstOrDefault().Handler.PlatformView as Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Window;
                  IntPtr windowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
                  Microsoft.UI.WindowId windowId = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(windowHandle);
                  Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(windowId);
                appWindow.SetPresenter(Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindowPresenterKind.FullScreen);
            //   (appWindow.Presenter as Microsoft.UI.Windowing.OverlappedPresenter).Maximize();
            // this line can maximize the window
#endif
      }
```